# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1;
    elif n % 2:
        n + f(n - 2)
    else:
        n * f(n - 1)

print(f(84))
```

В какой-то определенный момент функция решает возвращать `NoneType`, только я не понимаю почему. В чем проблема?

Comment: каждый вызов функции должен чтото венуть. и если не указать что, то функция вернёт None. в вашем случае вызовы дойдут до возврата 1 и патом начнёт возврат нонов что и приводит к ошибке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что код только при одном условии возвращает значение (это при условии n<=1), а в остальных случаях возвращает None. return поможет исправить ошибку.

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    elif n % 2:
        return n + f(n - 2)
    else:
        return n * f(n - 1)

print(f(84))
>> 148176
```